# How to update three tables in one query using mysql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm unable to find the answer for the update three tables in one query.
I've three tables named order1,order2,order3.in every table there are all column  field are fixed like teacher_name,kitname,kit_quantity,total_amt,paid.
now i want to update the paid column record as "Paid" where ever paid is there using condition.
can anyone help me in this.i realy need to finished this project.these tables are as follows:

```
order1              
id  teacher_name    kitname kit_quantity    total_amt   paid
1   Amrish Bhoi product 1   2   600 unpaid
2   Geeta Naik  product2    5   4500    paid
3   geeta naik  product1    2   100 unpaid
4   Amrish Bhoi product3    1   200 paid

order2              
id  teacher_name    kitname kit_quantity    total_amt   paid
1   Shindhu Sakpal  product 3   2   600 Paid
2   Geeta Naik  product2    5   4500    paid
3   geeta naik  product1    2   100 unpaid
4   Amrish Bhoi product3    4   200 unpaid

order3              
id  teacher_name    kitname kit_quantity    total_amt   paid
1   Amrish Bhoi product 1   2   600 unpaid
2   Geeta Naik  product2    5   4500    paid
3   Harsha Kale product4    3   1800    unpaid
4   Amrish Bhoi product3    1   200 paid
5   Amrish Bhoi product3    1   600 unpaid
```

Comment: build three individual query then run using mysql_multi _query()

Comment: is this helpful?..bcoz once i tried to update three sql stmt in one query using mysql_query().but it wont help me.but lets see i'l try this solution.thank you

Comment: mysql multi query different from mysql query..try mysql multi query .

Comment: I don't understand the db schema. can't you just have all the orders in the same table? They are equal..

Comment: @JimL It's possibly a un-normalized database.

Comment: There can surely be no sensible reason for having 3 order tables

Comment: @harsha FYI this is a terrible database structure. Consider reading [this](http://www.computerweekly.com/tutorial/Database-normalization-in-MySQL-Four-quick-and-easy-steps) to help you with that. And, I don't understand your question... what is the condition? You want to change `paid` to `Paid`?

Comment: yes @Ivan86 ..I want to update the record details where column name 'paid ' has unpaid value like update table1 set paid="Paid" where teacher_name="Amrish Bhoi" and paid="Unpaid"

Comment: can i make udatequery for tables like : update order1,order2,order2 set paid='Paid' where teacher_name="AMrish Bhoi" and paid="Unpaid"

Answer (score 0):

To update `three tables` with `same structure` but `different names` you can use a `list of table names` and use a `foreach loop` like this:

```
<?php

    $tableNames = array("order1", "order2", "order3");

    foreach($tableNames as $table)
    {
        $query = 'UPDATE '.$table.' SET paid = "Paid" WHERE paid = "unpaid"';
        mysqli_query($dbCon, $query);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ithink this will be helpful for me.I'l try to use the same logic.thank you

Comment: @harsha let me know if it works for you. If it doesn't you have other problems (image path problems).